# sort xslt with data composed of both text and numerical values

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I would like to sort data 
This is the xml file

```
<item name="HOUSE 10">
</item>
<item name="HOUSE 2">
</item>
<item name="MY 3 APPARTMENT">
</item>
<item name="MY 15 APPARTMENT">
</item>
```

I would like to get:
"HOUSE 2,HOUSE 10, MY 3 APPARTMENT, MY 15 APPARTMENT"

But I get 
"HOUSE 10,HOUSE 2, MY 15 APPARTMENT 15, MY 3 APPARTMENT"

NOTE

I am really really SORRY

of course    HOUSE must come before MY

Sorry I did not really understand your remarks until now

END OF NOTE

My xlst is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//item>
<xsl:sort data-type="number" select="./@name"/>
</xsl>
```

How can I make it ?

EDITED1: there is no "logic" about the number or position of numerical values in the labels, the numerical values can be placed anywhere.

EIDTED2:
I came up with an idea and I am almost there

I created a Java function
This function concatenes the number with the postion of the highest digit.
basically it returns

```
HOUSE 10 => HOUSE 210
HOUSE 2 => HOUSE 12
MY 3 APPARTMENT => MY 13 APPARTMENT
MY 15 APPARTMENT => MY 215 APPARTMENT

public static String concateneHighestDigit(String name){
    Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)"); // 

    Matcher matcher = digitPattern.matcher(name);
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    int i = 0;
    while (matcher.find())
    {
         matcher.appendReplacement(result, String.valueOf(matcher.group(1).length())+ matcher.group(1));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(result);
    System.out.println("result :" + result);
    return result.toString();

}
```

and in the xlst I have

```
 <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="special:concateneHighestDigit(./@name)"/>
```

where

```
  special
```

correponds to a customized xmlns

It still does not work, but I think I am not too far

Comment: "*there are no fixed number of words*" Is there anything that **is** fixed in the input? If I were to to suggest that you use only the **digits** in the @name attribute, you may change the example to "MY 3rd APPARTMENT #15" - and what then?

Comment: I have answered your remark in a new edit

Comment: No, you haven't: what if there are two (or more) numerical values?

Comment: "*EDITED2: there can be sveral numbers*" You are asking for a mind reader. I wouldn't know how to sort your entries "correctly" if doing this manually. By what logic does "MY 3 APPARTMENT" come **before** "HOUSE 2"?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about in EDITED3. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

By changing form "number" to "text", it works.
Still I do not understand why

```
<xsl:sort data-type="text" select="special:concateneHighestDigit(./@name)"/>
```

Thanks to you all for your support and your remarks ! 
It really helped to debug !

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting a string as number. It won't sort correctly.

Also, you want to order strings by character order, and the numbers by numerical order. To achieve this you have to separate the terms and order strings and numbers separately. You can do this with two `xsl:sort`s:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
    <xsl:sort data-type="text"   select="substring-before(@name, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="substring-after(@name, ' ')"/>
    <item><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></item>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This will work considering you have *one* word followed by *one* number, since `substring-before` and `substring-after` will return the strings before or after the *first* space.

**UPDATE**

You edited your question with new requirements:

- there is *one* number and it can appear anywhere in the text;
- the text may have spaces anywhere.

You can still use the two `xs:sort` expressions. You just have to find a way to extract the numbers and the strings to use them in ordering. If you can use **XSLT 2.0** then you can use a regular expression for that. This code removes the digits or the non-digits to obtain the sorting data for each case:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
     <xsl:sort data-type="text" select="normalize-space(replace(@name, '\d+',''))"/>
     <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="normalize-space(replace(@name, '\D+',''))"/>
     <item><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></item>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: edit: thanks a lot helderdarocha ! Unfortunately I have a random number of words and a number which can be placed at any place.

Comment: In that case, if you can find a pattern where you can identify and extract your number from the string, you can still use two `sorts`. You can achieve that with `substring` functions, and if you are using XSLT 2.0, you can use regex.

Comment: the only pattern is numerical values somewhere in the date

Answer (score 1):

Saxon has a collation that will do this kind of sorting:

```
<xsl:sort select="@name" collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?alphanumeric=yes"/>
```

This will sort "house 2" before "house 10". But it will sort "house 2" before "my 3 apartment", because "h" sorts before "m".

Comment: Thanks a lot, of course "h" with sort before "m" I made a big mistake now I have edited